# Google AppEngine /_ah/spi/BackendService.getApiConfigs 500

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine

For a while now, I am getting NullPointerExceptions when I am uploading my Google App Engine Project.
The deployment process itself seems reports ok, but I cannot access the functions from the Client.

I've tried it with different SDK Versions (incl. 1.9.15) of the Google SDK.

I use Eclipse. I've tried Luna, Kepler, Mars, but it does not Change anything.

I also tried another AppEngine Project, even another Google Account and uploading it using appcfg.cmd. But nothing helps.

Running the code on localhost-server works.

```
 2014-11-15 07:13:51.433 /_ah/spi/BackendService.getApiConfigs 500  9ms  6kb module=default version=1
 10.1.0.41 - - [15/Nov/2014:07:13:51 -0800] "POST /_ah/spi/BackendService.getApiConfigs
 HTTP/1.1" 500 6496 - - "1-dot-cluedupde.appspot.com" ms=10 cpu_ms=42 cpm_usd=0.000726
 app_engine_release=1.9.16 instance=00c61b117c4edc0ec3d5cd6d69d54161b6511e
 W 
 2014-11-15 07:13:51.430  /_ah/spi/BackendService.getApiConfigs
 java.lang.NullPointerException
     at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet.execute(SystemServiceServlet.java:147)
     at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet.doPost(SystemServiceServlet.java:118)
     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
     at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
     at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter ServletHandler.java:1166)
```

Comment: backends have been deprecated for some time now ... #justsaying

Comment: Ok, seems as if I had to migrate to the new modules - and it works. I just wouldn't have expected that it does not work anymore at all - even though it was deprecated.